# Prestashop 1.6.1.5 ajax-cart.js Update Layer except category

Tags: javascript, ajax, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

how can i modifiy my ajax-cart.js that not visible the add to cart popup if i select a product from a custom category.
The code is here (ajax-cart.js, row 720)

updateLayer : function(product){

```
    $('#layer_cart_product_title').text(product.name);
        $('#layer_cart_product_attributes').text('');
        if (product.hasAttributes && product.hasAttributes == true)
        $('#layer_cart_product_attributes').html(product.attributes);
        $('#layer_cart_product_price').text(product.price);
    $('#layer_cart_product_quantity').text(product.quantity);
    $('.layer_cart_img').html('<img class="layer_cart_img img-responsive" src="' + product.image + '" alt="' + product.name + '" title="' + product.name + '" />');

    var n = parseInt($(window).scrollTop()) + 'px';

    $('.layer_cart_overlay').css('width','100%');
        $('.layer_cart_overlay').css('height','100%');
    $('.layer_cart_overlay').show();
    $('#layer_cart').css({'top': n}).fadeIn('fast');
    crossselling_serialScroll();
    },
```

i need something like this : if (product.id_category_default == 95) then dont use the code, otherwise -> code

Comment: nobody knows about that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the default template the file to edit is:
`themes/default-bootstrap/modules/blockcart/blockcart-json.tpl`

```
// Add new line after row #32
"id_category_default" : {$product.id_category_default|intval},
```

Done. Now you can use this var in that function after you add a product in cart ;)